# Highcharts - resize legend on chart resize?

Tags: highcharts

Is there anyway to dynamically set a specific width of legend items when resizing the chart? I have some really long item names possible in the legend so I need to specify a width to force the text to wrap, but I would like to change the width when the width the chart changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a better work around for this:

```
chart.legend.options.width = newwidth;
chart.legend.itemStyle.width = newwidth;
for(var index in this.chart.series) {
        chart.legend.destroyItem(chart.series[index]);
}
chart.legend.render()
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is not possible, but you can disable highcharts legend, and prepare your own div (positioned absolutely) which will include list of all series and click event. Simple example is available here

```
$legend = $('#customLegend');

    $.each(chart.series[0].data, function (j, data) {

        $legend.append('<div class="item"><div class="symbol" style="background-color:'+data.color+'"></div><div class="serieName" id="">' + data.name + '</div></div>');

    });

    $('#customLegend .item').click(function(){
        var inx = $(this).index(),
            point = chart.series[0].data[inx];

        if(point.visible)
            point.setVisible(false);
        else
            point.setVisible(true);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N3KAC/10/

Than only what you need is adapt this to your chart by catching $(window).resize() function and resize element.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to add the custom legend to exported images? Or is there maybe a way to destroy and redraw the highcharts legend?

Comment: Oh nevermind actually. I realized I can just set useHTML:true and then change the width of the legend items using jquery. `$('.highcharts-legend-item span').width(800)` I don't why this didn't occur to me on Friday. Thanks though!